# Error "Ambiguous column name SubscriberKey"

Tags: mysql, sql, count

```
Select A.SubscriberKey, COUNT(DISTINCT EventDate) AS Count,B.CreatedDate
From _Open A
JOIN _ListSubscribers B
ON A.SubscriberKey = B.SubscriberKey
Where B.ListID = '10630'
Group By SubscriberKey
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT EventDate) = 1
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify the table that the column comes from as the same column name exists in both tables.

i.e. use `Group By A.SubscriberKey` as that is what you have in the `SELECT` list.

Also all RDBMSs except for MySQL will require you to also add `B.CreatedDate` to the `GROUP BY` list as that is in the SELECT list

Comment: @realrx7 - Shouldn't get the same error about ambiguous `SubscriberKey`. Sure it isn't a different column name or different complaint? What RDBMS are you using? All except for MySQL will require you to also `GROUP BY B.CreatedDate` as that is in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Column 'C89596._ListSubscribers.CreatedDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @realrx7 - Yes you need to add that to the `GROUP BY` list too as per my edit. i.e. use `GROUP BY  A.SubscriberKey, B.CreatedDate`

Comment: @realrx7, you got two different errors and you should have recognized that if you were reading them and trying to figure out what they meant. Both of these errors are straightforward and simple to interpret and the fact that you couldn't is not a good sign. Calling for help every time you have something that doesn't work the first time means that you will never understand what you are doing and will never go higher than junior devloper.

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one table that contains a column named after that name, so you need to specify the table containing the column referred to in your `Group By SubscriberKey`:

```
Group By A.SubscriberKey
```

Comment: I then get this error......Column 'C89596._ListSubscribers.CreatedDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.